# undefined reference to gdImageString

Tags: undefined-reference

I'm trying to compile a program called Contrafold and I need two libraries (libgd and libpng), the problem is a link the libraries but it through me an undefined reference error, I don't know why....My code to compile is the follow:

```
g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -W -pipe -Wundef -Winline --param large-function-growth=100000 -Wall EncapsulatedPostScript.o PlotRNA.o SStruct.o Utilities.o -o plot_rna -lm -L/path-to-library/libgd.a -L/path-to-library/libpng16.a
```

and the errors are:

```
PlotRNA.cpp:(.text+0x189e): undefined reference to `gdImageString'
PlotRNA.cpp:(.text+0x1a34): undefined reference to `gdImageFilledArc'
PlotRNA.cpp:(.text+0x1a79): undefined reference to `gdImageSetAntiAliased'
PlotRNA.cpp:(.text+0x1ad6): undefined reference to `gdImageChar'
PlotRNA.cpp:(.text+0x1c76): undefined reference to `gdImageLine'
PlotRNA.cpp:(.text+0x1fce): undefined reference to `gdImageString'
PlotRNA.cpp:(.text+0x2036): undefined reference to `gdImageCreateTrueColor'
PlotRNA.cpp:(.text+0x2079): undefined reference to `gdImageColorAllocate'
PlotRNA.cpp:(.text+0x2093): undefined reference to `gdImageColorAllocate'
PlotRNA.cpp:(.text+0x213a): undefined reference to `gdImageColorAllocate'
PlotRNA.cpp:(.text+0x217d): undefined reference to `gdImageFilledRectangle'
PlotRNA.cpp:(.text+0x2182): undefined reference to `gdFontGetMediumBold'
PlotRNA.cpp:(.text+0x218f): undefined reference to `gdFontGetSmall'
PlotRNA.cpp:(.text+0x223b): undefined reference to `gdImagePng'
PlotRNA.cpp:(.text+0x2250): undefined reference to `gdImageDestroy'
```

Any options?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to add linking with library containing gd* functions: -lgd

Comment: If I run
g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -W -pipe -Wundef -Winline --param large-function-growth=100000 -Wall EncapsulatedPostScript.o PlotRNA.o SStruct.o Utilities.o -o plot_rna -lm -lgd -L/path-to-library/libgd.a -L/path-to-library/libpng16.a

The error is:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgd

Comment: -L argument shouldn't contain name of library - only directory name - just remove libgd.a from -L parameter

Comment: Ok, now I put this

g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -W -pipe -Wundef -Winline --param large-function-growth=100000 -Wall  EncapsulatedPostScript.o PlotRNA.o SStruct.o Utilities.o -o plot_rna -lm -lgd -L/path-to-library/libgd/ -lpng -L/path-to-library/libpng/
And the error is

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng

But in libpng I have libpng.a

Comment: I think it should be libpng.so file not libpng.a in /path-to-libpng/. Maybe you have not installed libpng-devel rpm/deb package.

Comment: Ok...seems better than when I started, now just have one error.
My command is,
g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -W -pipe -Wundef -Winline --param large-function-growth=100000 -Wall  EncapsulatedPostScript.o PlotRNA.o SStruct.o Utilities.o -lm -lgd -L/var/www/html/Bioinformatics/tools/Ribomaker/contrafold/src/libgd/ -lpng16 -L/var/www/html/Bioinformatics/tools/Ribomaker/contrafold/src/libpng -o plot_rna

And the error is just one undefined reference

PlotRNA.cpp:(.text+0x223b): undefined reference to `gdImagePng'

Comment: You have to find 'gdImagePng' function in your library files (*.so) and add it with -l.

Comment: I found the function and the result was...
Binary file /path-to-library/libgd.so matches

I have run this command
grep gdImagePng /path-to-library/libgd.so

Comment: I don't know how can continue beyond the step above, what I need/have to do?

Comment: Is it libgd.so the only file which contains gdIMagePng or maybe there are other *.so ones?

Comment: What is output of: "nm libgd.so |grep gdImagePng" ?

Comment: I also this command and the result was that 000000000000f720 T gdImagePngToSink

But I don't understand the meaning

Comment: If this is the only result of this command - it seems that your library doesn't contain gdImagePng function at all. It's hard to me to say why. Maybe libgd is too old, or maybe there is also another library which contains gdImagePng.

Comment: Ok, thank you....I have downloaded 2.1.0 Version, 2.1.0-RC2 Version, 2.0.35-RC1 Version and no ones has gdImagePng, all of them have 000000000000f720 T gdImagePngToSink

Comment: Maybe this function has been removed from libgd in newer versions? I have version 2.0.35 and there is such function.

Comment: Which version? 2.035RC1 or 2.0.35RC2? Because I have 2.0.35RC1 too and I haven't this function

Comment: 2.0.35 without any RC on Fedora system.

Comment: Ok I'm gonna try to download this version, and after that I will say you again what happened, wish me good luck hehe

Comment: Ok...I'm here again, I downloaded gd-2.0.35 I did configure and make in my Ubuntu O.S., and I found gdImagePng and the result was the same, after run nm libgd.so |grep gdImagePng, my system has found 000109e0 T gdImagePngToSink

So....I can't understand nothing...

Comment: So - you recompiled gd-2.0.35 manually? Maybe ./configure doesn't find some library (PNG?) and because of this didn't make gdImagePng procedure.

Comment: I downloaded, 2.0.1, and in libgd16.so.2.0.0.so I have the function gdImagePng, so...now I'm trying the follow command:
g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -W -pipe -Wundef -Winline --param large-function-growth=100000 -Wall  EncapsulatedPostScript.o PlotRNA.o SStruct.o Utilities.o -lm -lgd -L /PATH/libgb -lpng16 -L/PATH/libpng -l/PATH/gd-2.0.1/libgd.so.2.0.0 -o plot_rna

And the error is that:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/PATH/gd-2.0.1/libgd.so.2.0.0

Comment: The same error like previous. Use -l/PATH/gd-2.0.1/ - remove the library name.